# why I cannot download documents If subfolder name of document library contains "+" symbol

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am using sharepoint 2007 portal.
In document library I have created one folder and named it as "Cards + Payments"
I am able to upload document in that folder but when I try to download, it is throwing error.
Error popup message is - "The Internet address "path of the document" is not valid"
But when I remove + symbol then it gets downloaded.
I know this is not a programming question but thought of posting here to get an answer to this issue.

Comment: to which internet address does the file point to?

Comment: file is pointing to the same address where it is residing i.e. in library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue. Since plus signs are special characters in a URL (just like ampersands and qusesiton marks), you should avoid using them.  A file with any of these special characters would fail to upload to SharePoint.  Since the file itself doesn't contain the plus, SharePoint doesn't complain, but once you try to download the file, the plus sign comes into play.

[Here is an article](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2010/02/03/sharepoint-hates-plus-signs/) describing the same issue.

Comment: Hi Robert,Thanks for explaination. Now it is clear to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling the URL directly, you'll need to convert the filename into a URL string. Using a handy online tool such as [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) one, I came to the conclusion that your filename converts to:

Cards%20%2B%20Payments

Also, if you download the file through the SharePoint API, you shouldn't have any problems calling the file by name. You should only run into this if, for some reason, you need to call the URL of the file directly, or create a hyperlink to a specific file.